# Using JOOQ in AWS Lambda

Tags: orm, aws-lambda, jooq

Have anyone tried using JOOQ with AWS lambda? I am using the same working config I have from my previous project that runs on tomcat and transitioned it to lambda. Lambda is not getting passed the query part. However if I run standard prepared statement everything is working ok so it is not a VPC/access or any other infrastructure issue.

Jooq code: 
`final Street street = DSL.using(configuration).select(STREET.fields()).from(STREET)                     .where(STREET.ADDRESS.eq(message.address())                        .fetchOneInto(Street.class));`

I am initializing config:

```
@Bean
public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
    DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
    jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
    jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(exceptionTransformer()));

    String sqlDialectName = environment.getRequiredProperty("jooq.sql.dialect");
    SQLDialect dialect = SQLDialect.valueOf(sqlDialectName);
    jooqConfiguration.set(dialect);

    return jooqConfiguration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, there was an issue with the query. JOOQ works great!